# Phoenix Framework empty Ecto migrate file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Im learning phoenix through the book Programming Phoenix.  All is well until I got stuck at trying to create a migration file with Ecto by running `mix ecto.gen.migration create_user`.  After running the above command i got

```
* creating priv/repo/migrations
* creating priv/repo/migrations/20170413160546_create_user.exs
```

in the `20170413160546_create_user.exs` file i got

```
defmodule Rumbl.Repo.Migrations.CreateUser do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do

  end
end
```

in the change function it doesn't generate anything like it was suppose to in the book.  I don't know what went wrong, or how to fix it. I'm hoping someone would help.

My user.ex model

```
defmodule Rumbl.User do
  use Rumbl.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    field :username, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string

    timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: `mix ecto.gen.migration` will generate a blank migration. You must have misread something. Maybe there's a `mix phoenix.gen.model User ...` or similar somewhere?

Comment: Sorry! i misread the book.  I was suppose to fill in the empty change function.  I got this all sorted out thanks.

Comment: I did the same misread now reading this book. Thx! lol

Answer (score 0):

mix ecto.gen.migration generates a blank migration. You have to fill in the change function